# Updating a caption of a text box when something is changed in the userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that has a dropdown of choices and each choice has different information related to it. to make sure the user has selected the correct Item that they want I have created a sentence in the spreadsheet which updates with the relevant information. I would like this sentence to be displayed on the userform when anything is updated on the userform i.e. if a different item is selected from the dropdown, the caption of the textbox will also update.

is there a way of doing this? I am currently using the following but it seems to only update some of the time:

```
Private Sub Item_No_TB_Change()

        Confirm_Info_Update.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email").Range("B60").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe try to put the `TextBox.value = blablabla` in the ComboBox event. But first it need a range something like this : cell A1 value = a, B1 value = bla, cell A2 value = b, B2 value = blu, cell A3 value = c, B3 value = ble. Each value in A1 to A3 is the same value in the ComboBox dropdown list. So in the ComboBox event, TextBox value = find ComboBox.value in range A1:A3 then offset(0,1).

Comment: If your userform is liked to the sheet such that changing the dropdown updates the content of B60 then you might need to add in a `DoEvents` or explicitly call the `Range.Calculate` event to ensure it's updated before you read the value.

Comment: I have added the following to the code but it does not seem to work, when I select a value from the dropdown and press enter it updates but when I change that value again the dropdown it does not change again.

Comment: DoEvents _ Thisworkbook.Sheets("Email").Range("B62").Calculate _ Confirm_Info_Update.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email").Range("B60").Value